# Possible to use C# codeDOM to call back to pre-compiled functions?

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm working on a silly game where the player controls their character by programming procedures for it to follow. I'm using C# codeDOM to compile the code the player writes and I'd like for the player to be able to call functions written into the pre-compiled part of the software. For example:

Player-written code to be compiled at run-time by codeDOM:

```
namespace AutoCrawl
{
    public class Player
    {
        public void Go_Up()
        {
            Move("Up");
        }
    }
}
```

My pre-compiled code:

```
    private void compileUserCode()
    {
        string code = UserCodeTextBox.Text;

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
    }

    private void Move(string direction)
    {
        //move the player's character in the direction specified by "direction"
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the codeDOM compiler that it can find the function `'Move'` in my own, pre-compiled code. I get the following error from the codeDOM compiler:

> Error (CS0103): The name 'Move' does not exist in the current context

Is it even possible? I can't seem to find any examples of other people using codeDOM in this way.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is set the ReferencedAssemblies property on your CompilerParameters to be a lib that contains your additional code.

```
var parameters = CompilerParameters
{
    ReferencedAssemblies = {
    "my.dll",
    // etc
    }
};
```

Here is a longer blog post on the subject including link to github
http://danielslaterblog.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/programming-programming-computer-game.html

Comment: If I make a library my.dll and add the function Move() to it, then I can add a reference to that library to the complied user code, right? If I write Move() into that context, will it be able to access variables generated at runtime such as the dungeon structure? What I mean is that the main, pre-compiled code generates variables that the function Move() needs to check. It needs to make sure that the user isn't trying to move through a wall, for example.

Comment: I have an example of doing exactly this at home. I'll post it on github later today and put the link here.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! That's very generous of you!

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've had a look through your blog post. It is right on target for what I need, I think. I really appreciate the time it took you to type up your post and share your work. Thank you!